# How to get accuracy of an expanded query (User input an query which is expanded for better IR)?

Tags: nlp, precision, information-retrieval

Using an algorithm , I am taking an input user query and expanding it. Now I need to test accuracy for my algorithm that is I want to get accuracy ( precision and recall ) for my expanded query ?

I have used terrier and taking a Trec Dataset(having collection of documents), 
I took a random query and retrieved relevant documents using terrier, then I used my algorithm to get expanded query for the random query and retrieved relevant documents.

But I dont know how to get precision and recall using this method.

So how do i get accuracy for my expanded query ?

If any other tool can be used ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TREC datasets (along with a set of queries and a document collection) have associated [relevance judgments](https://trec.nist.gov/data/reljudge_eng.html) for each query.

To measure the "accuracy" (effectiveness) of your query expansion method, you need to test it on the down-stream retrieval performance, i.e. you should consider your query expansion to be effective if it improves the retrieval (in terms of standard measures such as mean average precision or P@5).

Use the [trec_eval](https://trec.nist.gov/trec_eval/) tool to evaluate the effectiveness of retrieval both before (baseline) and after your query expansion method.

Comment: Thank you so much !. Also , are the document title considered as the queries ? Cannot find separate test queries for many documents ?